# How to make separate setting panels for dynamically created objects in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a theoretical question, so no reproducible example here. Let's say I have a number of dynamically created objects (any kind), and each of them has an attached button that opens the settings menu for this exact object (preferrably as a separate window). For example, I have a few dynamically created rectangles with buttons attached. Every button opens the settings panel for the exact rectangle it belongs to, so if I change rectangle's color or size from the menu, other rectangles should not be affected by this change. The settings are identical for every object, so all the menus and rectangles are virtually the same. The question is what's the correct way to implement this in qml? If it matters the object are created like this and are stored in an array.

```
var component;
var marker;

function createMarker() {
    component = Qt.createComponent("Marker.qml");
    marker = component.createObject(root);

    if (marker === null) {
        console.log("Error creating object");
    } else {
        return marker;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean the [Settings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html) component? Maybe you could use unique **file names** or **categories**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For page navigation, I prefer StackView with a push/pop mechanism.

```
    StackView {
        id: stackView
        initialItem: "MainPage.qml"
    }
    //...
    Button {
        onClicked: stackView.push("SettingsPage.qml")
    }
```

For dynamic objects, I prefer appending to a ListModel and realizing in a view control such as GridView.

```
    ListModel {
        id: listModel
    }
    GridView {
        model: listModel
        // ...
    }
```

For a settings page, I prefer pushing a page with an index to that ListModel.

```
    GridView {
        model: listModel
        delegate: Button {
            onClicked: stackView.push("SettingsPage.qml",{editIndex:index});
        }
    }
```

If `ListModel` is declared at the top level item, its scope will be 'global', in that it will be available to all children pages of the `StackView`. This means all pages will be available to read and write the contents. Any edits made to the ListModel will be propagated back to the GridView.

Here's an example:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    id: page
    header: Frame {
        RowLayout {
            width: parent.width
            Button {
                text: "Back"
                enabled: stackView.depth > 1
                onClicked: stackView.pop()
            }
        }
    }
    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: "MainPage.qml"
    }
    ListModel {
        id: listModel
        function appendItem(num, col) {
            append( { num, col } );
        }
        function appendRandom() {
            let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            let colors = `aliceblue aqua coral goldenrod violet haki firebrick pink
orange silver seashell salmon royalblue red orchid olive linen yellow lime #6080a0
`.split(/\s+/);
            let col = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
            appendItem(num,col);
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) appendRandom();
        }
    }
}

// MainPage.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Page {
    GridView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: listModel
        cellWidth: 200
        cellHeight: 200
        clip: true
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            width: 20
        }
        delegate: Frame {
            width: 180
            height: 180
            background: Rectangle {
                color: col
            }
            Button {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: num
                onClicked: stackView.push( "SettingsPage.qml", { editIndex: index } )
            }
        }
    }
    footer: Frame {
        RowLayout {
            width: parent.width
            Button {
                text: "Add"
                onClicked: listModel.appendRandom()
            }
            Button {
                text: "Clear"
                enabled: listModel.count
                onClicked: listModel.clear()
            }
        }
    }
}

// SettingsPage.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Page {
    property int editIndex: 0
    ColumnLayout {
        Text {
            text: "editIndex: " + editIndex
        }
        Frame {
            Layout.preferredWidth: 180
            Layout.preferredHeight: 180
            background: Rectangle {
                color: listModel.get(editIndex).col
            }
            Button {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: listModel.get(editIndex).num
            }
        }
        TextField {
            text:  listModel.get(editIndex).num
            onTextChanged: listModel.setProperty(editIndex, "num", parseInt(text))
        }
        TextField {
            text: listModel.get(editIndex).col
            onTextChanged: listModel.setProperty(editIndex, "col", text);
        }
    }
    footer: Frame {
        RowLayout {
            width: parent.width
            Button {
                text: "Delete"
                enabled: listModel.count
                onClicked: {
                    listModel.remove(editIndex);
                    stackView.pop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Answer (score 0):

Every time component.createObject (root);
It make a new item initialized using default parms of component (ex: color).
Once they are created, they don't share params. Changing param of one item doesn't change another create item.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense.